# Python multiple word input Caesar Cipher

Tags: python

I need help encoding a message in python. Right now the code takes an input and runs it through the cipher but doesn't include the spaces if a user enters more than one word.

```
user_input = input("Enter the secret message: ")
shift = int(input("How much do you want to shift?"))

def caesar(user_input, shift): 
  cipherText = ""
  for ch in user_input:
    if ch.isalpha():
      stayInAlphabet = ord(ch) + shift 
      if stayInAlphabet > ord('z'):
        stayInAlphabet -= 26
      finalLetter = chr(stayInAlphabet)
      cipherText += finalLetter
  print ("Your ciphertext is: ", cipherText)
  return cipherText

caesar(user_input, shift)
```

Comment: What do you want to do to the spaces? Your `for` loop doesn't have a case to handle the situation where `ch.isalpha()` is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the main thing to watch out for is that the space character isn't considered part of the alphabet (logicaly) and thus an extra elif must be added to take care of that case.

```
user_input = input("Enter the secret message: ")
shift = int(input("How much do you want to shift?"))

def caesar(user_input, shift): 
  cipherText = ""
  for ch in user_input:
    if ch.isalpha():
      stayInAlphabet = ord(ch) + shift 
      stayInAlphabet -= ord("a") # reset it from 0 to 25
      stayInAlphabet%=26 #modulo to limit it
      stayInAlphabet += ord("a") # re-add shift
      finalLetter = chr(stayInAlphabet)
    elif ch == ' ':
        finalLetter = ' '
    cipherText += finalLetter
  print ("Your ciphertext is: ", cipherText)
  return cipherText

caesar(user_input, shift)
```

Comment: There are other characters outside of the alphabetical or `' '` that will be missed here like numbers. Without having the spec that OP is using for the Caesar cipher we don't necessarily know how the other character classes should be handled, but you will want to at least do something with them

Comment: When is goes beyond the 26 letters and loops around it appears to do special characters such as `,[,],etc. Do you have a way to avoid this?

Comment: I updated the answer with a potential fix, the modulo is to acomodate for very large shifts.